# PlayerPerfs not working when user kill task via task manager Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i'm working on a game for android, i got a problem :

when i kill task via task manager on android the playerperf from unity not working, i had used OnApplicationQuit(), but it didn't saved when i kill task via task manager, but quit from quit button (which call Application.Quit()) works fine on android.

Anyone have the solution how to make playerperf work when user kill task via android task manager ? i'm using C# and Unity 5

Comment: override the onDestroy() method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

In the Android activity lifecycle you can't really depend on your application being available to safely store data past its onPause state. The practice for native Android apps is to save any data you need by overriding the onPause() function.

In Unity, this maps to OnApplicationPause.

I wouldn't count on being able to safely guarantee any data can or will be saved past this point.